# Issue in calling PHP file in loop over SSL

Tags: php, image, ssl, https

I am facing strange issue while loading multiple images in loop over SSL (in https). I tried debugging the code and found **loadImg.php**, which is responsible for loading image is not getting called all the time. However this is not happening while using non-SSL (in http).

**loadImg.php**

```
<?php
  $imageId = $_GET['id'];
  echo "Inside loadImg:".$imageId."<br/>";
?>
```

**HTML PAGE**

```
<?php 
for ($imgCtr = 0; $imgCtr < $imgCount; $imgCtr++) {
   $imageId = $listOfImg[$imgCtr]['pId'];
   echo "Inside HTML:".$imageId."<br/>";
?>
   <img src="loadImg.php?id=<?php echo $imageId; ?>">
<?php
}
?>
```

**Result**
Inside HTML:1
Inside HTML:2
Inside HTML:4
Inside HTML:6
Inside HTML:5
Inside HTML:3
Inside HTML:8
Inside HTML:7
Inside loadImg:1
Inside loadImg:2
Inside loadImg:4
Inside loadImg:5
Inside loadImg:8

Clearly ImageId = 6,7,3 missing.
However it is not happening in non SSL. Please guide me to resolve this.

Comment: How are you seeing the result `Inside loadImg x` when it's inside a `<img>`-tag?

Comment: I have printed the ids in log. Code is just for representation.